# Unable to Run Aries2 Locally - Error: Target is this Node

Tags: java

Trying to run an Aries 2 service locally and getting an exception:

```
SEVERE: [localhost]:7750 [local] [4.2.2] Target is this node! -> [localhost]:7750
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target is this node! -> [localhost]:7750
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OutboundResponseHandler.checkTarget(OutboundResponseHandler.java:226)

Sep 26, 2022 4:38:40 PM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl
WARNING: [localhost]:7750 [local] [4.2.2] While sending op error... op: com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.operations.JoinMastershipClaimOp{serviceName='hz:core:clusterService', identityHash=753771767, partitionId=-1, replicaIndex=0, callId=1, invocationTime=1664224720443 (2022-09-26 16:38:40.443), waitTimeout=-1, callTimeout=60000, tenantControl=com.hazelcast.spi.impl.tenantcontrol.NoopTenantControl@0}, error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target is this node! -> [localhost]:7750
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target is this node! -> [localhost]:7750, response: ErrorResponse{callId=1, urgent=true, cause=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target is this node! -> [localhost]:7750}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to determine the cause of this error, but I did workaround it by recompiling and rebuilding the Eclipse launcher and then copying over the VM options from Eclipse to IntelliJ.